# parse html data from iframe in anoter domain

Tags: iframe

Hi i have an application in http://abc.def.aspx and I want to parse the contents (basically a report) existing in   http://uvw.xyz.html . I have created an iframe in def.aspx page but it gives me permission error. I just want to parse the html content to allow new sorting features to the page. Can anyone point me to the right direction please

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the iframe for security reasons (if its a different domain)

The only solution I can suggest is if you have server side logic, you can go get the html of the different domain and parse the content on the server first.

Comment: I cant do that because siteminder comes inbetween and gives me a login page. When I try to enter my credentials it just redirects me again to the same login page. Whereas when I try to login in a browser with same credentials it accepts and renders the web page. Do you have a workaround for this ?